# Finding when an account was created

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I've been working on a command of which you input a user's ID an it will send an embed with their username, their discriminator and their profile picture.

I was wondering if is possible to also add the creation date of the user's account into the code.

Then once that's there, i'd like to add a section whether it says that they're a bot or not.

Answer (score 0):

A very lazy answer but it's my way of saying you should check the documentation: [User#createdAt](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createdAt)

Comment: Yea, i've checked the documents, and i've used it correctly and it doesn't show when the account was created, it just shows the date and time right now.

Comment: As you can see here: https://gyazo.com/37338ae131bb9a315e8b6e8ab1ae2223

I want to be able to search up any user by ID, then get their information back,

Comment: Did you try to get the createdTimestamp and convert it to UNIX time?

Comment: Also, show your code so I can see if you are doing anything wrong

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by createdTimestamp and convert it. but here's the needed code: 
let userid = args[0]

let accMade = `${moment.utc(userid.createdAt).format("dddd, Do MMMM YYYY, HH:mm:ss")}`

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=createdTimestamp

Comment: Yeah, i understand that, but i don't know how to do that, and the docs don't really give a full explanation

Comment: What does userid contain?

Comment: UserID is the args inputted into the command. Say they type !test 344152550448168970 It would search the whole of discord for that users ID and then return the results found about it, for example, the account creation, if they're a bot, their full name with discriminators.

Comment: Thanks for your help, in my case it was success.createdAt, rather than userid.createdAt.

Comment: Haha, this is why I asked for what UserID stored.

Comment: This is related to a different issue, how would i display someone's status - i have `success.presence.status` - but it always shows offline when searching for a different user.